# Calling an AJAX function to a PHP function script in a REST (Paypal) section, works in jQuery not in REST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, paypal

I'm in a bit of braiunfreeze here, puzzling for hours.

In a Paypal REST success section, i am trying to call a function. Before I moved it to the REST section I tested with a regular button onclick event. Worked fine.

Here the code:

```
        ...
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute()
            .then(function() {
                // window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'functions.php',
                    //dataType: "json",
                    data: {cuf_credits: '<?php echo $cuf_credits; ?>'},     
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#output").text("Thanks for buying " + data.cuf_credits + " credits");
                    }
                });
                // Show a thank-you note
                document.querySelector('#paypal-button-container').style.display = 'none';
                document.querySelector('#thanks').style.display = 'block';
                document.querySelector('#orderdetails').style.display = 'none';         
            });
    }
...
```

The query selectors are filled in fine, so is some basic text in the jQuery success section They return "undefined" though, but that is fine, I'm just trying to SEND, not GET back data.

The functions inside the functions.php are not executed, but when I use it in this code, it is:

```
var testme = document.getElementById('test');
testme.onclick = function () {
    console.log('Test Started');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'functions.php',
                    data: {cuf_credits: '<?php echo $cuf_credits; ?>'},     
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    function error(err) {
    console.log('Not Closed!');     

    }   
};
```

If anybody could point me back in the right direction, that'd be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Let's try some debugging...

Modify your `AJAX` block like so:

```
...
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute()
            .then(function() {
                // window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                //check to make sure your code is getting this far
                ////////start debug
                console.log("Calling AJAX...");
                ////////end debug
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'functions.php',
                    //dataType: "json",
                    data: {cuf_credits: '<?php echo $cuf_credits; ?>'},     
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#output").text("Thanks for buying " + data.cuf_credits + " credits");
                    }
                    //add a 'complete' function to get the status of the call
                    ////////start debug
                    complete: function(obj, textStatus){
                        console.log("AJAX Status: " + textStatus);
                    }
                    ////////end debug
                });
                // Show a thank-you note
                document.querySelector('#paypal-button-container').style.display = 'none';
                document.querySelector('#thanks').style.display = 'block';
                document.querySelector('#orderdetails').style.display = 'none';         
            });
    }
...
```

Let me know what your console log looks like after trying this...

Comment: AJAX Status: success

Comment: This was expected though, since the $("#output").text("Thanks for buying " + data.cuf_credits + " credits"); was also already outputted in the correct section (with undefined data.cuf_credits which is fine since its not echo'ed in my functions)

Answer (score 0):

I tried hardcoding the variables and noticed they work fine then. Sorry for the mishap, seems to work okay after a couple hours of not looking at it and taking another approach. Again, I apologize.